# Connecting JMS to MQ using MQClient java and MQExplorer error JMSWMQ2013

Tags: java, jms, jndi, ibm-mq, mq

I am using MQexplorer to handle queue manager, and when I connect to MQ using JMS with JNDI lookup, using `qcf.createQueueConnection();` I am getting `JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager` error. All posts/blogs mention about this error, but they say to remove CHAUTH for queuemanager and so on... How do I work this out using MQExplorer? Please help me on this!

I am using MQ client(with JNDI on LDAP) connection which can connect remote machine(not bindings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually disabling CHLAUTH is NOT advised as doing so opens up your queue manager to the world. It's OK if this is a test queue manager. Using runmqsc you can disable channel authentication. In runmqsc issue "ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)" command to disable channel authentication.

Please read WMQ InfoCenter or Chapter 20 of this [redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg248087.pdf) or just search for T.Rob's posts in this forum on CHLAUTH. Few links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889953/unable-to-connect-to-queue-manager-in-websphere-mq-7-1/12914860#12914860), this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886627/websphere-mq-7-1-help-need-access-or-security/8886813#8886813)